# How to get non-overlapping date counts in SQL

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have two tables: logins and visits. `Logins` keeps track of dates that a user logins to a website and the `visits` table keeps track of each user visiting a website. I am having trouble trying to get the number of visit counts **between** each login date. For example, the tables look like this:

Logins

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       user_id       |    login_date    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-21    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-23    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         149         |    2016-02-07    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Visits

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       user_id       |    visit_date    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-21    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-21    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-22    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-23    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-24    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         149         |    2016-02-07    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would like for my resulting table to look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       user_id       |    login_date    |   visit_counts   | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-21    |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    2017-09-23    |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         149         |    2016-02-07    |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Currently I am joining both tables and a `count(visits.event_date)` where the `on` condition looks like this:

```
on visits.event_date <= logins.event_date
```

However this results in `visit_counts = 5`  for `user_id = 12` when `login_date is 2017-09-23` bc it is also including the dates prior to 2017-09-23.

Comment: postgres or hive? tag only one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `join`.  Use `union all`:

```
select user_id, login_date, sum(logins) as logins, sum(visits) as visits,
       sum(logins + visits) as total
from ((select user_id, login_date as dte, 1 as logins, 0 as visits
       from logins
      ) union all
      (select user_id, visit_date, 0, 1
       from visits
      )
     ) lv
group by user_id, dte;
```

This separates the visits and logins into two separate columns and then adds them all up.  Actually, two columns is not needed, it just makes it easier to see the individual totals as well as the total totals.

Comment: i'm sorry if this is asking too much, but can you explain why to me?